# Lefschetz fixed-point theorem on Bott and Tu

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

In the page 129 of the book Bott&Tu, they give an exercise that prove the Lefschetz fixed - point theorem.

More percisely, for a compact orientable manifold $M$ with dimension $n$, they assume the map $f:M \to M$ is transversal and set $\sigma_p=\mathrm{sgn}  det(Df|_p-I)$ for a fix point $p$. Then they ask reader to prove that $\int_{\Delta}{}\eta _{\Gamma}=L(f)=\Sigma_p \sigma_p$, here $\Delta$ is the diagonal of $M \times M$, and $\eta_{\Gamma}$ the poincare dual of $\Gamma_f$, which is the graph $(x,f(x))$, here $x \in M$, $L(f)$ the lefschetz number of map $f$.

Actually I can prove this theorem by using the  duality $H^k(M) \to H_{n-k}(M)$ and $H_i(M) \times H_j(M) \to H_{n-i-j}(M)$. Is there any approach that only use some knowledge mentioned in the book Bott&Tu ? Thanks!

Comment: The crazy notation $\int_\Delta \Gamma_f$ is totally yours, and not theirs. Yes, the approach is to use the Poincaré dual of the diagonal $\Delta$, which they have just derived.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, it is a typing error and I' ve edited it. Could you give a more explicit hint? My approach is considering the intgral \int_{M \times M}{} \eta_{\Gamma} \wedge \eta_{\Delta} and using the duality I mentioned to translate this integral to the sum of the sign of orientation that the point $\Gamma_f$ and the diagonal $\Delta$ intersect transversely. But I think Bott&Tu never mention this duality, So I come to ask a way that avoid using this duality. Thanks!